# How to add columns dynamically in a column family in cassandra using cql

Tags: cassandra

I want to add columns dynamically to this column family via code using cql.

```
CREATE COLUMN FAMILY blog_entry
WITH comparator = UTF8Type
AND key_validation_class=UTF8Type
AND default_validation_class = UTF8Type;
```

how shall I do it?

Comment: Shalu can you tell me if you are using any tool like Hector, datastax for this or planning to use.

Comment: Yes i am planning to use datastax

Comment: Also to elaborate my requirement i want to add columns like UUID, name whose value has spaces, date, price which is float dynamically to the column family

Comment: OK I am not too old in Casandra world but I have used Hector and found that once you have column family established in Keyspace then there are direct apis to create columns in column family. You do not have to explicitly modify the structure of column family say from cassandra-cli and new column will get added with the help of API. Apologies I am not aware of Datastax at this point of time.

Comment: Is this the pre-defined set of columns or you want to add more columns with time? If it is predefine then you have static column family and most of the time you will be just inserting/updating/querying/deleting the data.

Comment: I can use predefined columns but i m getting **hex byte** error i m inserting a string variable to a varchar defined column in cassandra.

Comment: Through Cassandra-cli you can use set <cf>['<key>']['<col>'] = <value>; not cql. Cassandra-cli is very limited in its functionality. You can use help set; in cassandra-cli to check this.

Comment: Can you send the column family definition and insert construct?

Comment: Also you would be using UTF8Type as there is no Varchar type in cassandra. Please check this http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/ddl/column_family#about-data-types-comparators-and-validators

Comment: Actually i have defined the column family through the cql shell.

Comment: Actually i have defined the column family through cql in my code. as **CREATE TABLE newdata (key uuid PRIMARY KEY,date varchar,abc varchar);** **INSERT INTO newdata(key,date,abc,name)VALUES(4e47a967-2822-46ef-a854-130213abdf0a,'2013-05-29','abc mnc','xyz');** and i am getting error `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: cannot parse 'abc mnc' as hex bytes`.

Comment: Please check following link for syntax to create table: http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html#createTableStmt

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is becoming something of a FAQ, so I wrote an in-depth explanation: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/does-cql-support-dynamic-columns-wide-rows

Comment: I am helped by his exercise as it cleared more things to me. Thanks jbellis.

Answer (score 4):

For this to work you have to first alter the table to add column and then insert will start working. I tried the above on cqlsh and it worked.

```
alter table newdata add column name varchar;
```

Please refer below link too:

[How to define dynamic column families in cassandra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456720/how-to-define-dynamic-column-families-in-cassandra)

Comment: Thanks harish your exercise cleared many doubt related to cql and cli

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE blog_entry ADD newcolumnname text;
```