# How to query Cassandra dynamic columns using DataStax Java driver?

Tags: cassandra

I have a schema that stores values in Cassandra in the following format.

RowKey: one

```
   => (name=field1, value=ABC, timestamp=1223232)

   => (name=field2, value=XYZ, timestamp=1223232121)

   => (name=field3, value=ADS, timestamp=122323222323)
```

When I query fields (field1, field2, field3) using DataStax java driver, I am getting undefined column error.  I heard that CQL 3 does not support dynamic columns. That being the case, how can I make it work with new version without making schema change?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/does-cql-support-dynamic-columns-wide-rows

Your query should be something like `SELECT * FROM <your cf> WHERE key=<key>`. 
Those `field` will become cells' values, not the column names, in CQL

Comment: Thanks. I found a solution for my problem by altering column family.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456720/how-to-define-dynamic-column-families-in-cassandra